# Unknown behavior of uint64_t datatype

Tags: c++

I am trying to store a very big number in a `uint64_t` like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    uint64_t ml = sizeof(void*)*(1<<63);
    cout << "ml=" << ml << "\n";
    const char* r;
    const char* mR=r+ml;
    return 0;
}
```

But I do not know why am I getting the output as 0, despite of storing it in a `uint64_t` datatype?

EDIT: `char* mR` is my memory buffer and I can increase my memory buffer to at most `ml`. I want to make use of 64GB RAM machine. So, can you suggest how much should I increment `mR` to..as I want to use all the available RAM. That is to what value should I set `ml` to?

Comment: Let the compiler help you: *warning: shift count >= width of type*

Comment: @chris Ok. Do which datatype do you suggest I should use. Actually later I want to increment the character pointer

Comment: If you want to increment a character pointer, such as `r`, you simply write `++r`. What you are doing with `ml` makes no sense for that purpose. Maybe you haven't described what you're trying to do well: try being more precise and detailed.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @chris char* mR is my memory buffer and I can increase my memory buffer to at most ml. I want to make use of 64GB RAM machine. So, can you suggest how much should I increment mR to..as I want to use all the available RAM

Comment: If you need to reserve a ton of memory like that (or any at all), use a vector and call `reserve` on it.

Comment: You seem very befuddled about memory and creating objects; I would suggest hitting the books / tutorials. Or maybe you're seeing a confusing behavior from your program and have come upon a _completely_ wrong guess as to what the behavior signifies. If so, try explaining what you are seeing happen that you don't want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allocate 64G of memory, that would be:

```
char* buffer = new char[64ULL * 1024 * 1024 * 1024];
```

or simply:

```
char* buffer = new char[1ULL << 36];
```

Note that 64G is 2^36 bytes, which is far, far less than the 2^63 number that you're trying to use. Although, typically when you use that much memory, it's because your program organically uses it through various operations... not by just allocating it in one large chunk.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
uint64_t ml = ((uint64_t)1)<<63;
```

or just

```
uint64_t ml = 0x8000000000000000;
```

Just `1 << 63` uses integers, and if the shift value is too big, it is undefined behavior. In you case, it may result in `0` due to overflow.

Please note that if you multiply `0x8000000000000000` by `sizeof(void*)`, you'll likely get overflow too.

Comment: Actually later I am using ml to increment character pointer will it work in that case?

Comment: Ok. I can change my data type. Is there some datatype which can accommodate larger values like (2^96) instead of (2^63)

Comment: @StegVerner We just set `ml` to "a big value". I did not quite understand how you want to use it to increment a character pointer later.

Comment: @StegVerner, A big integer library.

Comment: @chris Ok can you please give some explain. I am new to C++

Comment: [I don't get `0`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89db1c9e04bfab16). Actually, I don't even get that result in the first place. [This one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e03c665e54198c72) proves my point a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
uint64_t ml = sizeof(void*) * (1ULL << 63);
```

Because, as AlexD already said, 1 << 63 uses integers, and 1 << 63 is actually 0.

Comment: `1 << 63` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it actually is. According to section *5.8 Shift operators* of the standard: "The behaviour is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand."

Answer (score 0):

Even after you correct the shift to `(uint64_t)1 << 63`, if `sizeof(void*)` is any even number (and it assuredly is), then your product will be divisible by `2^64`, and thus be zero when stored in a `uint64_t`.